# js regex copy closest word before target word

Tags: javascript, regex

This task looks like easy but I can not solve it :(

Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/qzIGlZ/1

[image: Demo]

As you can see, I want to copy `abc3`, but regex find first word `var` and copy all `var` till `3`.

How to copy **starting from nearest `var` to my key word `3`**?

Now it works like this: find `var` and copy all till `3`

But I need it to work like this: find `var`, starts copy, but if find new `var` - start copy from that position.

p.s. I need solution not only for that example with "var name", I searching universal method to do "closest search starting with something and till something"

More difficult exapmles: [#1](https://regex101.com/r/uFQmwQ/1) [#2](https://regex101.com/r/NSzGKl/2)

p.p.s. This is NOT ONLY for JS.

Comment: you can use `\S` to match non-whitespace characters [`var (\S*) = 3`](https://regex101.com/r/qzIGlZ/2)

Comment: @Slai for only "var name" example - yes but not for all other examples, I need something universal like in "logic" in post.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That is the case when I exactly developing "JS code parser" (js unpacker section) and I need that think in regex :( And my question sounds like regex question (not only for JS) because I have same situation in other tasks when I need to copy something BEFORE key, not AFTER.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew p.s. If there is no way to do this or you do not know how to do it, this is not an excuse to put -1 and mark with a duplicate that does not solve the problem. And you saw it: `I need solution not only for that example with "var name", I searching universal method to do "closest search starting with something and till something"` ?

Comment: I changed it to the correct close reason, so still a duplicate. You may still rely on a tempered greedy token, as [shown here](https://regex101.com/r/uFQmwQ/2).